# Why would $_REQUEST return different values in different cases when getting the same parameter?

Tags: php, url, parameters, get, request

I have two URL's which contain the parameter "tour_date" which I am trying to read out in PHP. Running `$_REQUEST["tour_date"]` for the first URL:

.php?tour_id=336&tour_date=11/06/2010

returns the value of: 11/06/2010

While the second URL:

.php?tour_id=336&tour_date=11/06/2010

returns nothing. I've run the empty() method to test, and it indeed is not finding it. Any ideas on why this would happen? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

$_REQUEST is a superglobal that combines $_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIE (in this order by default)
if your POST or COOKIE also set tour_date to an empty string, then the REQUEST values get overwritten

Comment: Thanks for the thought, but I've tried using only $_GET on the parameter as well, and it still returned nothing.

Comment: Check for much more global things. Do `error_reporting(E_ALL)` as the first line of your php code. Follow that by `var_dump($_SERVER)`

Comment: No errors reported with error_reporting(E_ALL), and on var_dump($_SERVER) and var_dump($_REQUEST), nothing came up related to the field tour_date. Perhaps it could be due to the slashes in the parameter? But I'd think that would at least return the first characters before the slash, and that doesn't explain why it works in the other instance.

Comment: Then go back to the basics - make sure you're working with the correct file on the correct server. Make sure you're saving changes (uploading to FTP?). See if you have a certain module on apache that enforces restrictions (some security modules may)... Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You could try putting `var_dump($_REQUEST);` in your code to see if that points you in the right direction.

Also, make sure you don't have a comparison with only a single "=".

As in `if($_REQUEST["tour_date"] = ""){`. This will return true and also set tour_date to empty.